# AddRegions is not a function

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

Simple code for start App

```
   define(['marionette'],function (Marionette) {


       var  MyApp = new Backbone.Marionette.Application();

        MyApp.addInitializer(function(options) {

        })
        MyApp.addRegions({
            mainRegion: "#content"
        });
    })

// MarionetteJS (Backbone.Marionette)
// ----------------------------------
// v3.1.0
//     Backbone.js 1.3.3
```

How to fix ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of Marionette version 3 `addRegions` is no longer supported. Instead, you can specify your root `region` as below:

```
var App = Backbone.Marionette.Application.extend({
  region: '#content',
  initialize: function() {
    // init
  },
  onStart: function() {
    // start application
  }
});

var myApp = new App();
myApp.start();
```

You can check out the Marionette v3 [documentation](http://marionettejs.com/docs/master/marionette.application.html) for more.